# JSON SCHEMA conditional: how can I require the key name in some of the list?

Tags: json, require, jsonschema

The JSON schema I want to implement can constrain the attributes under name into a list, as fellow code, I want the name should be input, and the name object the name of people should be some of ["TOM", "JACK","LILY","BRUCE"].

```
{
  "NAME":{
      "TOM": "male",
      "JACK": "male"
  }
} #This object meets the requirements
{
  "NAME":{
      "TOM": "male",
      "LILY": "female"
      "BRUCE": "male"
  }
}  #This object meets the requirements
{
  "NAME":{
      "JERRY": "male",
      "LILY": "female"
      "BRUCE": "male"
  }
}  #This object not meets the requirements beacuse JERRY not in the list.
```

```
{
  "type": "object",
  "required": ["NAME"],
  "properties": {
    "NAME": {
      "type": "object",
      "required": [],
      "properties": {
        "TOM": {
          "type": "string"
        },
        "JACK": {
          "type": "string"
        },
        "LILY": {
          "type": "string"
        },
        "BRUCE": {
          "type": "string"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: ~~~
"minProperties": 1,
"maxProperties": 4,
~~~ 
I can use those to limit the number of  names, but I can not limit the name in the list.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use the `propertyNames` keyword...

> If the instance is an object, this keyword validates if every
> property name in the instance validates against the provided schema.
> Note the property name that the schema is testing will always be a
> string.

https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-handrews-json-schema-validation-01#section-6.5.8

```json
{
  "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-07/schema",
  "properties": {
    "NAME":{
      "propertyNames": {
        "enum": ["TOM", "JACK","LILY","BRUCE"]
      }
    }
  }
}
```

See it working here: https://jsonschema.dev/s/VQa7a

Comment: thanks @Relequestual I try it, and it works well.

Comment: I have one more question can help me for this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71672748/how-to-different-constraint-settings-for-objects-at-the-same-level-in-jsonschema)